# How can I create many images in SwiftUI with a loop

Tags: swiftui

I have an image 32x32 and I want to fill the whole screen with many images
So I thought I could use ForEach but it doesn't seem to work

```
ForEach(0..<5) {_ in
   Image("myImage")
}
```

this code creates 5 previews instead of 5 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to embed the code inside a Vstack or an Hstack.
That way it will know how to create those images (vertically or horizontally)

```
Vstack(spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0..<5) {_ in
       return Image("myImage")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `VStack` or `HStack` You can't do that. For more info just take a look on the Apple Documentation. Here in [Make the List Dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) you will get the information.